# Windows curl Batch file

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, curl, mailgun

I want to make a mailgun curl call using windows batch file. Since windows shell doesn't support multiple lines, how can I execute the below curl function in windows batch file?

```
curl -s --user 'api:key-xxxxxxxxxx' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxbxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org/messages \
    -F from='user <email@gmail.com>' \
    -F to='user <email@live.com>' \
    -F subject='Hello' \
    -F text='body!' \
    -F attachment=@test.txt \
```

### Update

When I tried to execute the command after removing the multiple lines it returned this error:

```
    curl -s --user 'api:key-xxxxxxxxxx' https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxbxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org/messages -F from='user  -F to='user  -F subject='Hello' -F text='body!' -F attachment=@test.txt 0<email@live.com 1>'
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

PS: The attachment file is in the same directory

Thanks!

Comment: put it all on one line? splitting multi-line like that is purely for readability...

Comment: @MarcB Yes mark in fact I tried executing the curl command removing the the multiple lines but I am still getting this wierd error:
`curl -s --user 'api:key-xxxxxxxxxxx' https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org/messages -F from='user  -F to='user  -F subject='Hello' -F text='body!' -F attachment=@test.txt 0<email@live.com 1>'`

Comment: `<` and `>` are shell metacharacters for redirection... As always, you ned to make sure any shell metacharacters are escaped if you DON'T want to be treated as metacharacters.

Comment: You have to put the `<>` between `"` or escape them with `^ `like in my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

simply on one line and put the `<>` redirection char between `"` or escape it with `^`:

```
curl -s --user 'api:key-xxxxxxxxxx' https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxbxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org/messages -F from="user <email@gmail.com>" -F to="user <email@live.com>" -F subject='Hello' -F text='body!' -F attachment=@test.txt
```

You can also create variable for each element :

```
set "$ApiKey=api:key-xxxxxxxxxx"
set "$Url=https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxbxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org/messages"
set "$From=email@gmail.com"
....

and then 

curl -s --user '%$ApiKey%' %$Url% -F from="user <%$From%>" -F to= ....
```

Comment: `simply on one line and put the <> redirection char between " or escape it with ^`
i still have no clue about how to do it. It will be really really helpful if you can help me with that.
Thanks

Comment: like this : `-F from="user <email@gmail.com>"` or like this : `-F from='user ^<email@gmail.com^>'`

Comment: Thanks for the help.. Really appreciated! This is what I did:
`curl -s --user "api:key-xxxxxxxxxxxx" https://api.mailgun.net/v3/xxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org/messages  -F from="user <email@gmail.com>" -F to="user <email@live.com>" -F subject="Hello" -F text="body!"`