# Run a webpage from task scheduler and close it when the task finish using bat file

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I created a bat file with the following code

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://localhost:8083/
```

The bat file should run the link `http://localhost:8083/`
then I created a time scheduler on the server that run this bat file every 5 min so in theory the link should be called every 5 min

my problem is that the bat file is only being called once and I can't see that every 5 min a new instance of IE is called to run the webpage thus the code inside the weblink is not being executed every 5 min

what do you think i should do to fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the explorer remains open. You can try [curl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35491256/9925593) or powershell `Invoke-WebRequest`.

Comment: can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the task is never closed, so you need to change your bat file using another client to call your endpoint. For example, ***curl***.

If you don't have ***curl*** follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353/how-do-i-install-and-use-curl-on-windows)

Here's an example that returns the server time:

ping.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(
  echo %date% %time%

  for /F %%x in ('curl http://localhost:3090/ping') do (
    echo %%~x
  )
)
```

Result:

```
C:\Users\Patricio>ping.bat
22/02/22 10:23:14,37
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    50  100    50    0     0     43      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--    43
{"serverTime":"2022-02-22T10:23:15.5282576-03:00"}
```